# Can I find the equation of a plane by using a number of line equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, 3d

I am interested in finding the representation of a 3D curve in space through the use of multiple lines.

For example: Let us take Zaha Hadid's building  (because it is an interesting and nuanced shape)

[image]

Now let us do some polynomial interpolation and obtain the equations for some lines on the front.

[image]

Now we obtain something like this:

`y = 3.271849*10^{2} 
-1.500864x10^{0} 
+9.150803*10^{-3}x^{2}
+3.242545*10^{-5}x^{3}
-2.80975*10^{-7}x^{4}
+3.932247*10^{-10}x^{5}`

And so forth.

This equation, for instance, represents the curve outlined by the red points.

The question is this: Can I use these equations to draw a 3D plane, and what method could I use? 
Alternatively, would I require lines defining the side view of this plane as well?
[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface

Comment: I think you want a 3D surface rather than a "3D plane", right?

Comment: As a sidenote: your polynomial is incapable of truly representing the curve in the photo, as that is not the curve of a functio. It curves around under itself on either side. To truly represent this curve, you will need a parametric equation.